# I want to save the on-click using JavaScript and JQuery whenever I click DivTag, and save it on screen and post it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, onclick

I implemented jquery javascript onclick to switch the opacity of div tag (0 and 100) whenever I clicked on the div tag. I used jquery and 
javascript by array, onclick, get element by Id and so on.

But even if I refresh the page, I want to save it in the database so that I can get a screen that I clicked.

So, is there a way to get the information to the database every time I click it? I want to use jquery as much as possible. Because I don't understand the link_to function of ruby on rails.

I tried to save data by using jquery but I failed. Since I use jquery onclick event again, changing multiple divs' opacity (by onclick) is gone.

```html
<table>
  <tr id="line1">
    <td class="timeTableCellTime">9:00</td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-1"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-2"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-3"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-4"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-5"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-6"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="time_td">
      <div class="timeTableCell" id="c1-7"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
var array = ['c1-1', 'c1-2', 'c1-3', 'c1-4', 'c1-5', 'c1-6', 'c1-7']

$('#line1 td').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).index();
  var element = document.getElementById(array[i - 1]);
  if (element.style.opacity === "100") {
    element.style.opacity = "0";
    element.style.transition = "0.2s";
  } else {
    element.style.opacity = "100";
    element.style.transition = "0.2s"
  }

});
```

```css
.timeTableCell {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-radius: 3px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.timeTableCell:hover {
  opacity: 100;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#c1-1,
#c2-1,
#c3-1,
#c4-1,
#c5-1,
#c6-1,
#c7-1,
#c8-1,
#c9-1,
#c10-1,
#c11-1,
#c12-1,
#c13-1 {
  background-image: url('cell_01.png');
}
```

Comment: You can use AJAX to send information from the client to the server without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cookie i think

here two function for cookie manipulation
[Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

first get the cookie with getCookie('key') if its null you start as new when the user click save it with setCookie('key','DIV_ID') if its not null you can do your selected div manipulation